# Firebase notification message is not displayed on tray icon?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'me using [this example](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging with my app.
Sending messages via Firebase console, both with target *user segment* and *topic* (topic is **news**) works. My app will display a toast which contains the message.

What I want is *notification message*, which will automatically displayed in Android notification tray, not toast. After reading [FCM concept](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), I tried this with curl:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=AAAA....ahjkdkhajksd"  -X POST -d '{ "to": "/topics/news", "notification": { "body":"foo", "title":"bar", "icon":""}}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

It displayed via `Toast` though, not Android notification tray. What could go possibly wrong here?

Comment: post your onMessageReceived method, If your app is open notification is passed to it otherwise directly shown in notification tray.

Comment: OK. Please have a look at my [MyFirebaseMessagingService.java](https://gist.github.com/anta40/c55b73884f6718b7d29450fa64b5282c), and as [NotificationUtil.java](https://gist.github.com/anta40/1ffcccc1b5ac560683fad32d9196801a)

Comment: Your code enters in "if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null)" condition and displays data?

Comment: While debugging, I found this:
`07-27 14:42:12.652 21985-22283/studio.emcorp.monitoringsiswa E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: From: /topics/news`
`07-27 14:42:12.652 21985-22283/studio.emcorp.monitoringsiswa E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: Notification Body: foo`


Yes, that block was reached and I got the message displayed with a Toast

Comment: then what is the issue? if you are able to show data in toast then show the same data in a notification instead.

Comment: Hi Usman. Well, still no luck in displaying notification. I tried Jay Patel's suggestion below, it didn't work either. Let me check my code again later...

Comment: if you are able to show toast then showing notification shouldn't be issue at all. Specially when there is no error or exception thrown

Answer (score -1):

Notifications are not shown automatically to notification bar in case your app is in the foreground. If you want your app to show notification even if your app is in the foreground you need to add following code.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
    try {
        String title = object.getString("title");
        String message = object.getString("message");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());

        b.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("Ticker")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNo = r.nextInt(100000000 + 1);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(randomNo, b.build());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this. No new notifications displayed on the notification tray, though.